# Delete Mobile Broadband Connection on Windows 8

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, 64-bit, mobile-broadband

How can I delete a mobile broadband connection on Windows 8 Pro (64bit).
I tried:

> **netsh mbn show profiles**

but all I get is:

> **There is no Mobile Broadband interface**

There are two Mobile Broadband connection on my laptop and I want to delete both of them.Unfortunately though only one of the two shows up and it doesn't give me the option to delete it.Here is a screenshot :

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem.

You go to

> **Control Panel -> System and Security -> System**

and on the right there is the link of the

> **Device Manager**.

Click that and then when the Device manager shows up you.On the top of the Device Manager windows there is a button which says

> **View**

you click that and there is an option which says :

> **Show hidden devices**

Then you have to find the Network adapters section and click the arrow which is placed on the beginning next to the Network adapters.When you click the arrow all the network adapters will show up including the ones which are hidden.You find the one which you want to delete and you press the right click.After that a small menu will pop up and it will give you the option to

> **Uninstall**

the network adapter you have right-clicked on.